# I want to insert a value daily every after 3 minutes in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

I want to insert a value daily every after 3 minute in asp.net C#

For example: today's date is `1 sep 2020`

My Insert Id is

```
01092020001
01092020002
01092020003
01092020004
"
"
"
01092020480.
```

This `Id` is inserted after every 3 minutes.

And changed after that every 12:00 A.M. o'clock

Next day id is `02092020001`

Comment: Do you want to insert a bunch of rows at the same time, that has a datetime field that for each row differs by 3 minutes? Or do you want something to happen every 3 minutes on the clock? I ask because the former is just a method that inserts a bunch of rows, but the latter is probably best suited for a worker or similar, not for a web application.

Comment: I want to insert a single row value only every after 3 minute

Comment: Then my suggestion would be a worker service running alongside your web application. Web applications aren't really suited for this kind of work since they can be recycled/restarted/loadbalanced/scaled out and should ideally only handle requests from clients. You could of course create an endpoint you hit every 3 minutes, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: If you really want to use the web application, start a thread or a long-running task that inserts something into the database and waits for 3 minutes, in a loop.

Comment: Ok thank sir. So is it possible to done with sql server?

Comment: Sir please give me the example of sql server if is it possible

Comment: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Answer (score 1):

Create a SQL Server Agent Job that runs your sproc on a schedule of every 3 minutes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver15